# Unbound Combobox communicate with the database

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2013, combobox

I have a table contain following columns:

`*Id(int)
*Name(nchar)
*Type(nchar) 
*Description(nchar)`

The table is in online database. And I use a dataset.xsd file and connection string to communicate between client and the online database.

I have one Combobox with three item in it (Type1, Type2, Type2), I want to fill the database Table column "Type" base on the user selection result of Combobox.
I don't know how to do that.
[image]

Here is some of the method I use:

```
`ADataSet = New DataSet
ATableAdapter = New DataSetTableAdapters.TableTableAdapter
ATableAdapter.Fill(ADataSet.Table) '(when loading)
ATableAdapter.Update(ADataSet.Table) '(when Editing or Adding)
ABindingSource = New BindingSource
`
```

Comment: Add and edit is to modify the combobox collection?

Comment: No. Add and Edit is Add or Edite record to the database

Comment: Then what are you trying to do, I don't understand

Comment: User select one stored item in the Combobox (Say "Type1"), click Add button, then the Column "Type" will be filled with "Type1"  in the database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give this a try and give me some feedback

```
    ATableAdapter.Fill(ADataSet,"Your_Table")       
    Dim dsNewRow As DataRow
    dsNewRow = ADataSet.Tables("Your_Table").NewRow()    
    dsNewRow.Item(0) = ID
    dsNewRow.Item(1) = Name
    dsNewRow.Item(2) = Type
    dsNewRow.Item(3) = Desc
    ADataSet.Tables("Your_Table").Rows.Add(dsNewRow)
    ATableAdapter.Update(ADataSet,"Your_Table")
    MsgBox(ID & " has successfully been added to the system.")
```